# Referring to an object's ID in a jQuery append statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this element:

```
<div class="isthisyou" id="unique_identifier"></div>
```

I want to use jQuery to insert a link into the div:

```
$('isthisyou').append('<a href="auth/create_account/'+this.id+'">Is this you?</a>');
```

Right now `this.id` is returning `undefined` instead of `unique_identifier`.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always this

```
$this = $('.isthisyou');
$this.append('<a href="auth/create_account/'+$this.attr('id')+'">Is this you?</a>');
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I changed $this to $myvar -- just so I wouldn't confuse myself by using the 'this' syntax in a variable I defined myself.

Comment: This code doesn't work properly with two or more items. If you only have one item, you could just hardcode the ID as well.

Answer (score 1):

It fails for three reasons:

1. The selector for class `foo` should be `".foo"` rather than `"foo"`
2. The ID is variable for each element; you cannot use the same value in the append() call
3. In your code, `this` does not mean what you thing it means

Try this instead:

```
$('.isthisyou').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<a href="auth/create_account/'+this.id+'">Is this you?</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For classes in selectors use it as ".classname" (the dot), and unfortunately you have to access the id through $(this).attr().

```
$('.isthisyou').append('<a href="auth/create_account/'+$(this).attr("id")+'">Is this you?</a>');
```

If $(this).attr("id") is still undefined than that means that $(this) isn't set inside the append and you're going to have to use the following:

```
$('.isthisyou').each(function(){
  $(this).append('<a href="auth/create_account/'+$(this).attr("id")+'">Is this you?</a>');
});
```

Comment: Returns an error that attr is not defined.  I think we might need a $ in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `attr` instead:

```
$('isthisyou').append('<a href="auth/create_account/'+$(this).attr('id')+'">Is this you?</a>');
```

Or as shown from the comments, you can try:

```
$('isthisyou').append('<a href="auth/create_account/'+$('isthisyou').attr('id')+'">Is this you?</a>');
```

Comment: This looks promising, but unfortunately $(this).attr('id') is still returning undefined when I try it out...

Comment: Yes.  I ended up using $('.isthisyou').attr('id') internally and it worked.  Wish there were a prettier way.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above answers have small problems.
Use

```
$('.isthisyou').append('<a href="auth/create_account/'+$(this).attr('id')+'">Is this you?</a>');
```

Comment: This creates a link auth/create_account/undefined.  Is $(this) referring to the literal string to be appended, instead of its parent?